# Can I say "Put 3 times the amount of water than soybeans"?

Tags: comparative, comparison

Can I say:

1. Put 3 times the amount of water than soybeans.

Or:

2. Put 3 times water than soybeans.
3. Put 3 times cups of water than soybeans.
4. Put 3 times the amount of water as soybeans.
5. Put 3 times as much as soybeans.

Which is the best expression in English or grammatically correct?

Comment: For a general answer to questions like this, you should look up the construction [**as much as**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/as-as).

Answer (score 3):

In recipes, the usual form is

"For every cup of soybeans, add 3 cups of water"

In the case where the ratio is 1:1

"Use equal amounts of oil and lemon juice"

Comment: The `backtick` is not a good format for either ELL or ELU. Check both sites' meta questions.